# How to send Audio through SoundCard Output channels 1/2 and 3/4 in PortAudio Callback function?

Tags: c, signal-processing, portaudio

Here is my simple callback. PA detects my soundcard with 8ins/8outs. I would like to send audio stream to output channels like 1/2 and 3/4 simultaneously. How can I do this in the callback? Thanks

```
int audioCallback ( const void* input, void* output, unsigned long samples,
                       const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void* userData)
    {
        const float *in = ( const float*)input;
        float *out = (float*)output;

        paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;


        for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
        {

            *out++ = *in++; // left Channel(1)
            *out++ = *in++; // right Channel(2)

        }


        return paContinue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example indicates that your input stream is stereo so try this:

s1 = *in++;
s2 = *in++;

*out++ = s1; //channel 1
*out++ = s2; //channel 2
*out++ = s1; //channel 3
*out++ = s2; //channel 4

The result should be that channel 1 and 3 play the same signal and channel 2 and 4 play the same signal

In most cases the channels are interleaved in the output buffer.  Otherwise the other channel pairs may be represented by different devices.